# bazel: Setting a global varible from environment variable

Tags: bazel

I need to use an environment variable in my bzl file. Right now its hardcoded like this

[PI_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT_DIR = "/home/dev/oosman/.leila/toolchains/rpi"](https://github.com/jambamamba/libedgetpu/blob/4120c6a212106e0ced8a59715eb5d9605051fff9/coral_crosstool1/cc_toolchain_config.bzl#L69)

I could probably read the environment variable in the _impl method below, but how do I set the global variable above.

```
def _impl(ctx):
    #todo: need to get this env variable and use it instead of hardcoded paths where ever rpi is defined above
    #PI_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT_DIR=${HOME}/${DOCKERUSER}/.leila/toolchains/rpi
    #ctx.os.environ.get("PI_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT_DIR", "/home/dev/oosman/.leila/toolchains/rpi") #osm
```

https://github.com/jambamamba/libedgetpu/blob/raspi0/coral_crosstool1/cc_toolchain_config.bzl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [repository rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/repository_rules.html) to generate a .bzl file. Something like this:

```py
def _impl(repository_ctx):
  repository_ctx.file("pi_toolchain_root.bzl", "PI_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT_DIR = \"%s\"" % \
      repository_ctx.os.environ.get("PI_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT_DIR", "/home/dev/oosman/.leila/toolchains/rpi"))

pi_toolchain_repository = repository_rule(
    implementation=_impl,
    environ = ["PI_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT_DIR"],
)
```

Then in your WORKSPACE you can write:

```py
load("//:wherever.bzl", "pi_toolchain_repository")
pi_toolchain_repository(name = "pi_toolchain")
```

and then (later on in WORKSPACE or in a BUILD or .bzl file):

```py
load("@pi_toolchain//:pi_toolchain_root.bzl", "PI_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT_DIR")
```